# Swift - How to mutate a struct object when iterating over it

Tags: swift, struct, copy, mutable

I am still not sure about the rules of struct copy or reference.

I want to mutate a struct object while iterating on it from an array:
For instance in this case I would like to change the background color
but the compiler is yelling at me

```
struct Options {
  var backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

var arrayOfMyStruct = [MyStruct]

...

for obj in arrayOfMyStruct {
  obj.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() // ! get an error
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`struct` are value types, thus in the `for` loop you are dealing with a copy.

Just as a test you might try this:

#### Swift 3:

```
struct Options {
   var backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}

var arrayOfMyStruct = [Options]()

for (index, _) in arrayOfMyStruct.enumerated() {
   arrayOfMyStruct[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

#### Swift 2:

```
struct Options {
    var backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

var arrayOfMyStruct = [Options]()

for (index, _) in enumerate(arrayOfMyStruct) {
    arrayOfMyStruct[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() 
}
```

Here you just enumerate the index, and access directly the value stored in the array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have one clarifying question: If you had specified a name for the current `MyStruct` object and since the array is passed by value, trying to print out the named struct object's `backgroundColor` on the next line would result in the old value being printed, correct?

Comment: This does not work for Swift 3, please see my answer below for Swift 3.

Answer (score 29):

You can use use [`Array.indices`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994726-indices):

```
for index in arrayOfMyStruct.indices {
    arrayOfMyStruct[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: Beware of the discussion from Apple's docs: `A collection’s indices property can hold a strong reference to the collection itself, causing the collection to be nonuniquely referenced. If you mutate the collection while iterating over its indices, a strong reference can result in an unexpected copy of the collection. To avoid the unexpected copy, use the index(after:) method starting with startIndex to produce indices instead.` Source: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1641719-indices]

Comment: The link in @Mihai Erös comment was moved to: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2949967-indices

Comment: @MihaiErős would this apply to `for (index, _) in arrayOfMyStruct.enumerated()` as well?

Comment: Correct link for the documentation page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1641719-indices

Comment: The enumerated() docs do not mention anything about that. Also I'd still use .indices just for the sake of clarity; but good to know to pay attention if you're handling a very large list.

Comment: The `strong reference` warning is now only part of the String collection (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/indices-swift.property), not the generic https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/indices

Answer (score 15):

You are working with `struct` objects which are copied to local variable when using `for in` loop. Also array is a `struct` object, so if you want to mutate all members of the array, you have to create modified copy of original array filled by modified copies of original objects.

```
arrayOfMyStructs = arrayOfMyStructs.map { el in
   var el = el
   el.backgroundColor = .red
   return el
}
```

It can be simplified by adding this Array extension.

**Swift 4/5**

```
extension Array {
    mutating func mutateEach(by transform: (inout Element) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        self = try map { el in
            var el = el
            try transform(&el)
            return el
        }
     }
}
```

**Usage**

```
arrayOfMyStructs.mutateEach { el in
    el.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For Swift 3, use the `enumerated()` method.**

For example:

```
for (index, _) in arrayOfMyStruct.enumerated() {
  arrayOfMyStruct[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() 
}
```

The tuple also includes a copy of the object, so you could use `for (index, object)` instead to get to the object directly, but since it's a copy you would not be able to mutate the array in this way, and should use the `index` to do so. To directly quote the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107):

> If you need the integer index of each item as well as its value, use
>   the enumerated() method to iterate over the array instead. For each
>   item in the array, the enumerated() method returns a tuple composed of
>   an integer and the item.

Comment: There's no need to use the enumerated method if you *only* need the indices. Just use `for i in 0..< arrayOfMyStruct.count`

Answer (score 1):

Another way not to write subscript expression every time.

```swift
struct Options {
    var backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}

var arrayOfMyStruct = [Options(), Options(), Options()]

for index in arrayOfMyStruct.indices {
    var option: Options {
        get { arrayOfMyStruct[index] }
        set { arrayOfMyStruct[index] = newValue }
    }
    option.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample code

```
arrayOfMyStruct.indices.forEach { arrayOfMyStruct[$0].backgroundColor=UIColor.red }
```

Answer (score -8):

I saw this method in some code and it seems to be working

```
for (var mutableStruct) in arrayOfMyStruct {
  mutableStruct.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Comment: That 'var' makes the item you are iterating over locally mutable (but does not change the backing struct).