# Strange syntax when try to iterate through the array of structs in swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have a simple array of structs

```
var fields: [ProfileField]?
```

when I try to iterate through this array, swift shows me error on this code:

```
guard let _fields = fields else {return}
for field in _fields {
}
```

the error is:

```
Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'field' is a 'let' constant
```

And this code compiles well:

```
for var field in _fields {
}
```

Why do I need to declare `field` as `var`?

Comment: @MikePollard guard let _fields = fields else {return}

Comment: I think you need to reveal what you're up to in your for loop

Comment: I guess you're doing something that mutates `field`

Comment: yes, it's try - but when my struct was a class - this code works well

Comment: Yes, when your struct was a class it was a reference. Now it's a struct and a value, which if you declare with let you can't change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777891/swift-how-to-mutate-a-struct-object-when-iterating-over-it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A “mutating getter” in Swift is a property whose `get` block has the `mutating` modifier. For example, if your `ProfileField` looked like this:

```
struct ProfileField {
    var accessCount: Int = 0

    var x: Int {
        mutating get {    // ← mutating getter here
            accessCount++
            return x
        }
    }
}
```

…then this code would generate your “Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value” error:

```
for field in _fields {
    print(field.x)
}
```

Even though it doesn’t *look* like `field.x` modifies `field`, it does: it increments `accessCount`. That’s why you must say `var field` to make field mutable. (For loop iterators are `let` by default.)

Without seeing either your `ProfileField` or the body of your for loop, it’s impossible to say exactly why this occurs in your case. If you are not using `mutating get` in `ProfileField` itself, it may be happening in a struct nested within `ProfileField`.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for the "Even though" - now I understand that accessCount is changing! Best of the best!

Comment: Glad it helped. Further surprising detail (that makes sense when you think about it): it’s not `accessCount++` that causes the compile error, but the word `mutating` itself. If a function modifies the struct, you have to declare it `mutating`, but the converse is not true. You can declare something `mutating` just to reserve the right to modify the struct even though you don’t. It’s an API choice.