# Swift can't update array in struct when cycling

Tags: swift

I have next code:

```
struct UserWorkoutsStruct {
        var workouts: [WorkoutEntity]
        var jsonKey: String
    }

func makeDataForSections(serverResponse: NSDictionary, completion: @escaping WorkoutsBySections) {

        let mine = UserWorkoutsStruct(workouts: [], jsonKey: "your")
        let last = UserWorkoutsStruct(workouts: [], jsonKey: "last")
        let today = UserWorkoutsStruct(workouts: [], jsonKey: "today")
        let other = UserWorkoutsStruct(workouts: [], jsonKey: "other")

        let allUserWorkouts = [mine, last, today, other]

        for var userWorkout in allUserWorkouts {

            if let workouts = serverResponse[userWorkout.jsonKey] as? [[String: Any]] {
                workouts.forEach { (element) in
                    let workout = WorkoutEntity.mr_import(from: element)
                    userWorkout.workouts.append(workout)
                }
            }
        }

        completion(mine.workouts, today.workouts, last.workouts, other.workouts)
    }
```

but all `mine.workouts, today.workouts, last.workouts, other.workouts` contain 0 elements.

But in cycle I see that `userWorkout.workouts.append` adding elements to array.

Comment: You are not even appending to your objects. First you would need to declare your structures as variables (now they are all constants, the same applies to your array (`allUserWorkouts`). Iterate the array indices and append to them using the index for subscription

Comment: Why don't you show your server response? It would probably be easier using Codable protocol

Comment: if I declare them as variable compiler says that consider replace to let and as you see from struct var workouts: [WorkoutEntity] is variable. thanks for help. by the way I tried to changed to vars and there is still no objects in arrays

Comment: JSON is mapped to MagicalRecord core data object. So there is no need in it. I just want to group workouts into different arrays.

Comment: looks like it's similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777891/swift-how-to-mutate-a-struct-object-when-iterating-over-it but not sure how it can help me, tried marked one, does not work. One different that I don't have colors instead i have arrays